# Adding widgets to existing frame and show a progress bar at the same time in wxpython

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, wxpython

I have a wxpython application, I start up the application and show the main frame. It has a button. When I press the button, I want a `pyprogress` (`wx.lib.agw.pyprogress`) show up, and I'd like to add 5 widgets to the main frame as the `pyprogress` is running. `pyprogress` should display messages like this: "adding widget 1", "adding widget 2"... I try to run the `pyprogress` in a seperate thread, but when I try to update the `pyprogress` message and add widgets to main frame at the same time, I get this error:

```
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\evtloop.cpp(182) in wxGUIEventLoop::Dispatch(): only the main thread can process Windows messages
```

How do I update `pyprogress` and add widgets to mainframe at the same time?

**UPDATE:**

The following code works without errors, and I have no idea how it works. It updates the GUI window and PyProgress window from threads and I don't get any `only the main thread can process Windows messages`. Please explain why it doesnt give any errors.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.pyprogress as PP
import threading

ID_ADD_BUTTON = 100
ID_ADD_BUTTON2 = 101

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "My Panel", size=(400,300))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.mytext = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Start", size=(20,-1))

        self.toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, -1, style=wx.TB_FLAT|wx.BORDER_RAISED)

        self.toolbar.AddLabelTool(ID_ADD_BUTTON, 'Refresh', wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PLUS))

        self.toolbar.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.refreshButton, id=ID_ADD_BUTTON)

        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)


    def refreshButton(self, event):
        self.myprogress = ProgressThread()
        self.toolbar2 = wx.ToolBar(self, -1, style=wx.TB_FLAT|wx.BORDER_RAISED)
        self.toolbar2.AddLabelTool(ID_ADD_BUTTON2, 'Print', wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PLUS))
        self.toolbar2.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.refreshButton, id=ID_ADD_BUTTON2)
        update = MyThread(self.mytext)

        self.toolbar2.Realize()
        self.myprogress.dlg.UpdatePulse("toolbar 2 is added")
        for i in xrange(250):
            self.myprogress.dlg.UpdatePulse(str(i))
        #print "toolbar 2 is added"

        self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.Layout()
        for i in xrange(8000, 8005):
            self.myprogress.dlg.UpdatePulse(str(i))
            toolbar2 = wx.ToolBar(self, -1, style=wx.TB_FLAT|wx.BORDER_RAISED)
            toolbar2.AddLabelTool(ID_ADD_BUTTON2, 'Print', wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_PLUS))
            toolbar2.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.refreshButton, id=ID_ADD_BUTTON2)
            toolbar2.Realize()


            self.toolbar2.Realize()
            self.sizer.Add(toolbar2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.myprogress.keepGoing = False

    def refreshButton2(self, event):
        print "button 2 is pressed"



class ProgressThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        style = wx.PD_APP_MODAL
        self.dlg = PP.PyProgress(None, -1, "Updating Data                      ",
                            "Please wait...",
                            agwStyle=style)
        self.start()

    def run(self):

        self.dlg.SetGaugeProportion(20/100.0)
        self.dlg.SetGaugeSteps(50)
        self.dlg.SetGaugeBackground(wx.WHITE)
        self.dlg.SetFirstGradientColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.dlg.SetSecondGradientColour(wx.GREEN)

        self.keepGoing = True


        while self.keepGoing:
            wx.MilliSleep(30)
            try:
                self.dlg.UpdatePulse()
            except:
                pass

        self.dlg.Destroy()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, my_text):
        self.my_text= my_text
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.start()

    def run(self):
        for i in xrange(300):
            self.my_text.SetLabel(str(i))

# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your UI code must be in the main thread. One options is that, you move your progress bar code into the main thread, and communicate with the separate thread that does the actual work. I usually define custom events and  PostEvent from the separate thread. There is a nice write-up about the topic here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: Please provide an example. I tried what you suggested but it won't work, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `wx.lib.pubsub` (`from wx.lib.pubsub import pub`)
Put your `gauge` or whatever in the main loop and

```
pub.subscribe(self.listener, 'Update-1')
```

for example.

Where `self.listener` is the function that updates the `gauge`, whilst in the thread you issue

```
pub.sendMessage('Update-1', data1=(a1), data2=(a2), data3=(a3))
```

messages, whenever something you want to use to update the progress bar has happened.
The listener function would look something like this:

```
# Sub Pub listener
def listener(self, data1, data2, data3):
    count = int(data1)
    size = int(data2)
    self.progress.SetRange(size)
    self.progress.SetValue(count)
    self.filehandle.SetValue(data3)
```

Where the UI is defined as:

```
self.progress = wx.Gauge(self.panel, pos=(10,155), size=(300,10),range=100)
self.filehandle = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1, pos=(10,170),size=(300,25), value="")
```

(This example is used for reporting the progress of a file download)

Comment: Thanks. How will the separate thread send messages to update the gauge?

Comment: As stated in the answer, pub.sendMessage('Update-1', data1=(a1), data2=(a2), data3=(a3))

Comment: But which thread will add widgets to GUI? Main thread or the separate thread?

Comment: pubsub isn't thread-safe as far as I know, so you'll need to wrap that in a `wx.CallAfter` to use it